# mongo atlas connection troubles

Tags: mongodb, meteor, digital-ocean

I have an app, created in meteor.js but it shouldn't be important i think. I have also mongo cluster on mongo atlas. So far during development i connected to db by connection string without problem from my local machine. However when i created linux machine on DigitalOcean and tried to connect my app using same connection string `mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@xyz.mongodb.net/<dbName>?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

I got the following error.

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [xyz.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to xyz.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/staging/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:440:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at net.js:675:12
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:568:7)]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/staging/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Pool.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at /home/ubuntu/staging/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14
    at /home/ubuntu/staging/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1009:9
    at callback (/home/ubuntu/staging/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:75:5)
    at /home/ubuntu/staging/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:101:9
    at _callback (/home/ubuntu/staging/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:329:7)
    at Connection.errorHandler (/home/ubuntu/staging/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:344:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/staging/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:438:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
```

Do you have any idea of what could be wrong with me server config? I guess it is server config as on other machine same connection string works.

Comment: check `network access` configuration, for example, if you use `IP Whitelist`, you may check whether your current IP is in the list

Comment: Things to check from your digital ocean instance: can you ping `xyz.mongodb.net`? what happens when you `telnet xyz.mongodb.net 27017`? What does the log on the atlas instance say, is there any indication of it rejecting the connection attempt?

Comment: @ChristianFritz ping: xyz.abaz9.mongodb.net:27017: Name or service not known telnet: could not resolve xyz.abaz9.mongodb.net:27017/telnet: Name or service not known. Shame on me but i dont see when isee logs on atlas instance.

Comment: You should not use a port number with ping; Please look again at what I asked to ping.

Comment: @ChristianFritz sorry. No problems with ping. telnet only prints Trying 18.193.58.103.

Comment: hm, but from your dev machine you can connect to that hostname and port? that's odd, then Digital Ocean is somehow blocking you from connecting to a foreign port of 27017, which doesn't make much sense.